# I want to upload a image and add URL of the image to firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

This is my first time using Firestore.I want to upload a image to storage in firebase and add URL of the image to firestore.
Image is upload in storage correctly but URL of the image didn't add to the firestore.
thank you for helping me find solution and I am open to any improvement for my code

```
  const uploadimage = () => {
    var urlF = [];
    var urlI = [];
    if (files != []) {
      files.map(async (file) => {
        // Upload file and metadata to the object 'images/mountains.jpg'
        await storageRef.child("files/" + file.name).put(file);
        var DownloadURL = await storage
          .ref("files")
          .child(file.name)
          .getDownloadURL();
        urlF.push(DownloadURL);
        seturlimage(urlI);
      });
    }
    if (images != []) {
      images.map(async (image) => {
        // Upload image and metadata to the object 'images/mountains.jpg'
        await storageRef.child("images/" + image.name).put(image);
        var DownloadURL = await storage
          .ref("images")
          .child(image.name)
          .getDownloadURL();
        urlI.push(DownloadURL);
        seturlfile(urlF);
      });
    }
  };
  const submit = async () => {
    uploadimage();

    await db
      .collection("users")
      .doc(currentUser.uid)
      .collection("products")
      .add({
        buildingName: buildingName,
        adress: adress,
        zipcode: zipcode,
        price: price,
        NumberOfRooms: NbrOfRooms,
        NumberOfBathRooms: NbrOfBathRooms,
        categorie: Cat,
        aminities: Ami,
        urlimage: urlimage,
        urlfile: urlfile,
        discerption: discerption,
        latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude,
        telephone:telephone
      })
    history.push("/products")
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `map` of an Array doesn't support async calls. That is probable the place where your problem starts. You can rewrite the code to use a simple `for` loop what supports `async` like here:

```js
const uploadimage = () => {
  var urlF = [];
  var urlI = [];
  if (files != []) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      const file = files[i];
      // Upload file and metadata to the object 'images/mountains.jpg'
      await storageRef.child("files/" + file.name).put(file);
      var DownloadURL = await storage
        .ref("files")
        .child(file.name)
        .getDownloadURL();
      urlF.push(DownloadURL);
      seturlimage(urlI);
    }
  }
  if (images != []) {
    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      const image = images[i];
      await storageRef.child("images/" + image.name).put(image);
      var DownloadURL = await storage
        .ref("images")
        .child(image.name)
        .getDownloadURL();
      urlI.push(DownloadURL);
      seturlfile(urlF);
    }
  }
};
const submit = async () => {
  uploadimage();

  await db.collection("users").doc(currentUser.uid).collection("products").add({
    buildingName: buildingName,
    adress: adress,
    zipcode: zipcode,
    price: price,
    NumberOfRooms: NbrOfRooms,
    NumberOfBathRooms: NbrOfBathRooms,
    categorie: Cat,
    aminities: Ami,
    urlimage: urlimage,
    urlfile: urlfile,
    discerption: discerption,
    latitude: latitude,
    longitude: longitude,
    telephone: telephone,
  });
  history.push("/products");
};
```

Or you could also rewrite the code to use `Promise.all` to upload all files in parallel so the code would execute faster.

Comment: still getting same problem

Comment: Can you pls console log the values of `files` and `images` to check if we have there something

Comment: Can you also chare the whole file you have there.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZzeX0XP1EYzgVyLjuDLMhutLsQt0E0c1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you confirm that `setfiles` is called after `uploadfile`? And did you check if `files` and `images` are empty or not?